# 2からNまでを、素因数分解したときの次数の和の順に並べるには？

Tags: アルゴリズム

以前
（[2からNまでを、素因数分解したときの素因数の最小値が小さい順に並べるには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10436/2%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89n%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%82%92-%E7%B4%A0%E5%9B%A0%E6%95%B0%E5%88%86%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E7%B4%A0%E5%9B%A0%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%80%E5%B0%8F%E5%80%A4%E3%81%8C%E5%B0%8F%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E9%A0%86%E3%81%AB%E4%B8%A6%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)
および
[2からNまでを、素因数分解したときの次数によって並べるには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10472/2%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89n%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%82%92-%E7%B4%A0%E5%9B%A0%E6%95%B0%E5%88%86%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E6%AC%A1%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E4%B8%A6%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)）
と異なる規則によって、2からNまでを並びかえを行います。

①2〜Nまでを素因数分解を行い次数のみ取り出しその和を求める。
②次数の和が小さい順に並べる。次数の和が同じなら、元の数の大きさが小さい方が先とする。

例えば、N = 10 の場合、次のようになります。
①
2 => 1,
3 => 1,
4 => 2,
5 => 1,
6 => 2,
7 => 1,
8 => 3,
9 => 2,
10 => 2
②
2, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8
となる。

一般のNに対し、この規則に従い2からNまでを並びかえを行うには
どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

参考までに何の工夫もしていないコード（Ruby）を挙げておきます。

```ruby
require 'prime'

N = 10
h = {}
(2..N).each{|i|
  s = 0
  i.prime_division.map{|j| s += j[1]}
  h.key?(s) ? h[s] = h[s].push(i) : h[s] = [i]
}
p h.values.flatten
```

（追記）
三回にわたって似たような質問をしたのは、
以下のようなコードを見つけるためでした。
これまでご回答いただいた方々へ厚く御礼申し上げます。

```ruby
require 'prime'

N = 51
ary = []
h = {}
(2..N).each{|i|
  if i.prime?
    ary.push(h.values)
    p h # 検証用の出力なので省いても構わない
    h = {1 => [i]}
  else
    s = 0
    i.prime_division.map{|j| s += j[1]}
    h.key?(s) ? h[s] = h[s].push(i) : h[s] = [i] # sは1, 2, … とは限らない
  end
}
p ary.push(h.values).flatten
```

出力結果（検証用の出力は省く）
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43,
 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 50]
↑
2〜51までを順番に出力したのではありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(別に大した方法じゃないですが) 素因数分解なし・ソートなしの方法

- 素因数分解はしたくないので、逆に合成する方針です
- 合成は @yoh2 さんと同様に次数和ごとに行いますが、1つ小さい次数和の結果を再利用します
- 別の配列 `degrees[2～N]` に生成した数の次数和を記録して、
  最後にそれを読み出すことでソートを免れます
- 時間計算量のオーダーは O(N) です(…多分)

※素数列の生成は、"Atkin の篩 <sup>[[参考URL](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/uwitenpen/20111203) by @Manyama さん][実装例: [Spaghetti Source](http://www.prefield.com/algorithm/math/sieve_of_atkin.html)]</sup>" を用いれば時間計算量 O(N/log log N) らしいので、全体としてもこの方針で O(N) な物を作れるはずです。残念ながら、Ruby の Prime は、エラトステネスの篩 (～O(N log log N)) の様ですが。

**Ruby コード**:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'prime'
include Math

def factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(n)
  maxDegree = log(n, 2).round
  degrees = Array.new(n + 1)

  # degrees[合成数]=次数和 の表を作る
  primes = Prime.each(n).to_a
  composites = [[1,0]] # [[合成数, 最大素因数], ...], 次数和0について初期化
  (1 .. maxDegree).each{|degree| # 次数和昇順ループ
    composites = composites.flat_map{|(u, i)|
      (i .. primes.length - 1).lazy
        .map{|j| [u * primes[j], j]}
        .take_while{|(v, j)| v <= n && ( degrees[v] = degree )}.force
    }
  }

  # 合成数を次数和毎に振り分けてから連結
  ret = Array.new(maxDegree + 1) { [] }
  (2 .. n).each{|i| ret[degrees[i]] << i}
  ret.flatten
end

p factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(10)
p factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(100)
```

**説明**:
(※面倒なので、素数や 1 も便宜上合成数に含めて呼んでしまいますが気にしないで下さい…)

先ず、「合成数 → 次数和」 のテーブル `degrees[合成数]` を作ります: 基本は次数和についてのループで、素因数を掛けていく事により合成数を生成しつつ `degrees[合成数]=次数和` をして行きます。テーブルさえ完成すれば、後は (質問文のコードと同様に) 次数和ごとに振り分けてから配列をくっつければ良いです。

合成数を生成する部分について、もう少し説明しておきます。

- 配列 `primes` は使う可能性のある素因数たちです。
- 配列 `composites` は現在の次数和(degree)における `[合成数, 最大素因数の番号]` たちを含みます。但し、`最大素因数の番号` は配列 `primes` におけるインデックスです。
- 初期の `composites` は、便宜的に、次数和 0 として 合成数 = 1, 最大素因数番号 = 0 を登録しておきます: `composites = [[1, 0]]`。
- 或る次数和の `composites` は、1つ下の次数和の合成数に素因数を1つかける事で生成します。ただし、重複して生成されないように「新しくかける素因数は現在の最大素因数以上」という制限をかけます。

**出力**:
[2, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 46, 49, 51, 55, 57, 58, 62, 65, 69, 74, 77, 82, 85, 86, 87, 91, 93, 94, 95, 8, 12, 18, 20, 27, 28, 30, 42, 44, 45, 50, 52, 63, 66, 68, 70, 75, 76, 78, 92, 98, 99, 16, 24, 36, 40, 54, 56, 60, 81, 84, 88, 90, 100, 32, 48, 72, 80, 64, 96]

---

おまけ

**愚直な実装(Ruby)** 素因数分解 × ソート (テスト用):

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'prime'

def factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(n)
  (2 .. n).sort_by{|v| [v.prime_division.map{|f| f[1]}.reduce(:+), v]}
end

p factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(10)
```

**重複組合せ(Ruby)** `repeated_combination` を使ってみる × ソート:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'prime'

def factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(n)
  primes = Prime.each(n).to_a
  (1 .. log(n, 2)).flat_map{|degree|
    limit = n / 2 ** (degree - 1)
    primes
      .select{|factor| factor <= limit}
      .repeated_combination(degree)
      .map{|factors| factors.reduce(:*)}
      .select{|value| value <= n }
      .sort
  }
end

p factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(10)
```

**C++版** (比較用):

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::int64_t value_type;

// エラトステネスの篩
//   実はこれなら割り算なしで素数列が作れる。但しメモリは食う。
template<typename OutputIterator>
void sieve_of_eratosthenes(OutputIterator output, value_type n) {
  std::vector<value_type> mark(n + 1, 0);
  value_type i = 2, imax = std::round(std::sqrt(n));
  for(; i <= imax; i++){
    if(mark[i])continue;
    *output++ = i;
    for(value_type j = i * 2; j <= n; j += i)
      mark[j] = 1;
  }
  for(; i <= n; i++)
    if(!mark[i])
      *output++ = i;
}

// 目的の数列を生成
template<typename OutputIterator>
void factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(OutputIterator output, value_type n) {
  int const maxDegree = std::round(std::log2(n));
  std::vector<value_type> degrees(n + 1, 0);

  // degrees[合成数]=次数和
  std::vector<value_type> primes;
  sieve_of_eratosthenes(std::back_inserter(primes), n);
  std::vector<std::pair<value_type, int> > composites = { std::make_pair(1, 0) }, composites2;
  for(int degree = 1; degree <= maxDegree; degree++) {
    composites2.clear();

    for(auto const& pair : composites){
      for(int j = pair.second; j < primes.size(); j++) {
        value_type const v = pair.first * primes[j];
        if(v > n)break;
        composites2.push_back(std::make_pair(v, j));
        degrees[v] = degree;
      }
    }

    composites.swap(composites2);
  }

  // 次数和で振り分け・連結
  std::vector<std::vector<value_type> > ret(maxDegree + 1);
  for(value_type i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    ret[degrees[i]].push_back(i);
  for(auto const& ret_ : ret)
    for(auto const& value : ret_)
      *output++ = value;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  value_type const n = 1 < argc ? std::atoi(argv[1]) : 10;

  std::vector<value_type> buff;
  buff.reserve(n);

  factorization_degree_ordered_sequence(std::back_inserter(buff), n);
  for(auto const& value : buff)
    std::cout << value << ", ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

---

編集: C++ コード追記しました。
編集: @Manyama さん御紹介の "Atkin の篩 参考URL" を追記しました。

Comment: 「Atkin の篩」等の話は、こちらのページが親切だと思っています。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/uwitenpen/20111203

Comment: ありがとうございます! 追記しました。

Answer (score 2):

次数和を中心に考えて、

- 次数和 = 1 で構築できる、 N 以下の合成数 (というか素数そのもの) のソート済リスト
- 次数和 = 2 で構築できる、 N 以下の合成数のソート済リスト
- 次数和 = 3 で...

と、得られるリストが空になるまで次数和を増やしていき、それらを結合するというのはどうでしょう。
この方法は、ベタに素因数分解をしていく方法よりコードは煩雑になりますが、リストを得る際の除算が不要になります。
とはいえ、素数リストを作るのに結局除算が必要になるので、本当に除算が減ってくれるか否かは微妙ですが。(未検証)

ruby はまともに書けないため、HaskellとC++で書いてみました。
最初からソート済のリストを得る方法が思い付かなかったため、そこは素直にソートしています (C++ではちょっと小細工していますが)。

(ruby って、素数リストが標準で入ってるんだよね。羨しい……)

Haskell 版。

```hs
import Data.List (sort)

-- 素数の無限リスト。
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2 :  filter (\x -> and $ map ((/= 0) . (mod x))
                                $ takeWhile (\y -> y * y <= x) primes)
                     [3, 5 ..]

-- 昇順リスト xs から重複を許して選んだ
-- n 個の要素すべてと currの積がmaxを超えない
-- ような積の全リスト。
-- 関数名は、悩んだ挙句投げやりなものに。
theProducts :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer -> Int -> [Integer]
theProducts _      _   curr 0 = [curr]
theProducts (x:xs) max curr n = if (x * curr) > max then []
                                else theProducts (x:xs) max (x * curr) (n - 1)
                                     ++ theProducts xs max curr n

-- max 以下で、次数合計が 1 のもの, 2 のもの... (それぞれソート済)
-- を、空リストが返ってくるまで求め、それらを結合する
-- ことで解とする。
solve :: Integer -> [Integer]
solve max = foldl1 (++) $ takeWhile (/= []) $ map (sort . theProducts primes max 1) [1..]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ solve 100
```

結果:
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,4,6,9,10,14,15,21,22,25,26,33,34,35,38,39,46,49,51,55,57,58,62,65,69,74,77,82,85,86,87,91,93,94,95,8,12,18,20,27,28,30,42,44,45,50,52,63,66,68,70,75,76,78,92,98,99,16,24,36,40,54,56,60,81,84,88,90,100,32,48,72,80,64,96]

C++ (C++11) 版。素数リストを有限リストにしただけで、ほぼHaskell版のベタ移植。そして長い……
合成数を `std::set` に放り込むことで、最後にまとめてソートせずに済むようにしています。

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using num_t = int;

// max 以下の素数のリストを得る。ただし2は必ず含まれる (手抜き)。
std::list<num_t> get_primes(num_t max)
{
    std::list<num_t> primes;
    for(num_t n = 3; n <= max; n += 2)
    {
        bool is_prime = true;
        for(auto p : primes)
        {
            if(p * p > max)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(n % p == 0)
            {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(is_prime)
        {
            primes.push_back(n);
        }
    }
    primes.push_front(2);
    return std::move(primes);
}


// 昇順リスト [first, last) から重複を許して
// 選んだ n 個の要素すべてと curr の積が max を
// 超えないような積の集合を得る。
void get_list_products(
    std::set<num_t> &products,
    std::list<num_t>::const_iterator first,
    std::list<num_t>::const_iterator last,
    num_t max, num_t curr, int n)
{
    if(n <= 0)
    {
        products.insert(curr);
        return;
    }

    if((first == last) || (curr * *first > max))
    {
        return;
    }

    get_list_products(products, first, last, max, curr * *first, n - 1);
    get_list_products(products, ++first, last, max, curr, n);
}


int main()
{
    const num_t N = 100;
    std::vector<num_t> result;

    const auto primes = get_primes(N);

    for(int n = 1; ; n++)
    {
        std::set<num_t> products;
        get_list_products(products, primes.begin(), primes.end(), N, 1, n);
        if(products.empty())
        {
            break;
        }

        std::copy(products.begin(), products.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
    }

    for(auto x : result)
    {
        std::cout << x << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

結果:
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 46, 49, 51, 55, 57, 58, 62, 65, 69, 74, 77, 82, 85, 86, 87, 91, 93, 94, 95, 8, 12, 18, 20, 27, 28, 30, 42, 44, 45, 50, 52, 63, 66, 68, 70, 75, 76, 78, 92, 98, 99, 16, 24, 36, 40, 54, 56, 60, 81, 84, 88, 90, 100, 32, 48, 72, 80, 64, 96,